# UITextField UITextBorderStyleNone has lines everywhere in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios7, uitextborderstyle

I added a `UITextField` in Interface builder and selected `UITextBorderStyleNone`. However the text field has lines in it and partially around the border. See Image, the textfield in question is on the left:

[image: Four UITextFields with four different UITextBorderStyles]

Prior to iOS 7 I would have expected no border and no lines in that text field.

I tried setting the border in code

```
[self.textFieldXX setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

but no change.

When I set a red border (as a test) I see this

[image]

```
[self.textFieldXX.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[self.textFieldXX.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
```

What are those lines (vertical and top/bottom border) in the text fields and how to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got strange behavior for font size > 16.